# Django: TypeError at /login/ __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to update Django version to 3.2.5 from 1.9 in my simple project, and all looks good. But when I try to access the Login page, I get the following error in the browser:

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:49801/login/
Django Version:     3.2.5
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Exception Location:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 181, in _get_response
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe
Python Version:     3.7.8
Python Path:    

['C:\\source\\repos\\aud',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:49801/login/
Django Version: 3.2.5
Python Version: 3.7.8
Installed Applications:
['app',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /login/
Exception Value: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Additional info from settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'app.context_processors.cart',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db import models
from.models import Comment, Blog, OptionsModel, Order

class BootstrapAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    """Authentication form which uses boostrap CSS."""
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=254,
                               widget=forms.TextInput({
                                   'class': 'form-control',
                                   'placeholder': 'Имя пользователя'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"),
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput({
                                   'class': 'form-control',
                                   'placeholder':'Пароль пользователя'}))
```

urls.py:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.conf.urls import url, include
import django.contrib.auth.views

import app.forms, app.views

# Uncomment the next lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

from django.conf.urls.static import static 
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns 
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^about$', app.views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^links$', app.views.links, name='links'),
    url(r'^registration$', app.views.registration, name='registration'),

    url(r'^login/$',
        django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView,
        {
            'template_name': 'app/login.html',
            'authentication_form': app.forms.BootstrapAuthenticationForm,
            'extra_context':
            {
                'title': 'Вход пользователя',
                'year': datetime.now().year,
            }
        },
        name='login'),
    url(r'^logout$',
        django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView,
        {
            'next_page': '/',
        },
        name='logout'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.template import RequestContext
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.db import models
```

login.html:

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}
<!--♕-->
{% block content %}

<h2>{{ title }}</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            <form action="." method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <h4>Используйте аккаунт для входа.</h4>
                <hr />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_username" class="col-md-2 control-label">Имя пользователя</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        {{ form.username }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_password" class="col-md-2 control-label">Пароль</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        {{ form.password }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Войти" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                {% if form.errors %}
                    <p class="validation-summary-errors">Введите правильное имя пользователя и/или пароль.</p>
                {% endif %}

            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section id="socialLoginForm"></section>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}


{% block scripts %}

{% load static %}

<script src="{% static 'app/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

Also was updated many scripts: bootstrap.js and .css from 3 to v5.0.2; jquery from 1.10.2 to 3.6.0; jquery.validate.js and respond.js to latest versions.

If anyone has any insight as to why I'm getting this error, I'd appreciate it.

Updated url.py but with the same error (thx to Willem Van Onsem):

```
from django.conf.urls import include, re_path

re_path(r'^login/$',
    django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView.as_view(
    {
        'template_name': 'app/login.html',
        'authentication_form': app.forms.BootstrapAuthenticationForm,
        'extra_context':
        {
            'title': 'Вход пользователя',
            'year': datetime.now().year,
        }
    }),
    name='login'),
re_path(r'^logout$',
    django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView.as_view(
    {
        'next_page': '/',
    }),
    name='logout'),
```

Only with this code in urls.py, error was gone, but a new one comes:

```
re_path(r'^login/$',
    django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView.as_view(),
    name='login'),
re_path(r'^logout$',
    django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView.as_view(),
    name='logout'),
```

Error (because I can't transmit as_view({'template_name': 'app/login.html'}) ):

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /login/
registration/login.html
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:62067/login/
Django Version:     3.2.5
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    registration/login.html
```

Comment: Well it means that your `registration/login.html` template does not exists. Furthermore in the `.as_view()` you should *not* use a dictionary, but named parameters like in the answer.

Comment: In essence you thus use `.as_view(template_name='app/login.html')` not with a dictionary.

Comment: Thankyou, it works! template_name = 'app/login.html',
        authentication_form = app.forms.BootstrapAuthenticationForm,
        extra_context = { 'title': 'Вход пользователя', 'year': datetime.now().year }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LoginView` and `LogoutView` are *class-based views*, so you need to wrap it in a function with the [**`.as_view()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view):

```
url(
    r'^login/$',
    django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView.as_view(
        template_name='app/login.html',
        authentication_form=app.forms.BootstrapAuthenticationForm,
        extra_context{ 'title': 'Вход пользователя', 'year': datetime.now().year }
    )
    name='login'
),
url(
    r'^logout$',
    django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='/')
    name='logout'
)
```

---

> **Note**: As of [django-3.1](/questions/tagged/django-3.1), [**`url(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#url) is
> deprecated in favor of [**`re_path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/re-path).
> Furthermore a new syntax for paths has been introduced with path converters: you
> use [**`path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/path) for that.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I looked at other similar answers, but I didn't understand how to write the correct code. And now I have the next step. But I have the same error. I will update my question